# Unhandled exception: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal in UWP application

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-winrt

So I was making a polynomial simplifier for my school project. I decided to make the application using C++ UWP in Visual Studio.

As one of the extra features of the application I implemented a system to store and retrieve polynomials from a file so that you can access your previously entered polynomials. I am using `boost::filesystem` for this. The code compiles fine. But while debugging, this function:

```
fs::exists(basePath) // namespace fs = boost::filesystem
```

...is somehow causing the following exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFBB71AAFEC (ucrtbased.dll) in
> ExpressionSimplifierV4 UWP.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a
> function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

..thrown from this line:

```
rootFrame->Navigate(TypeName(MainPage::typeid), e->Arguments); // App.xaml.cpp
```

**My question:** *What is the cause of this exception* and *how do I resolve it*?

If any extra information is needed, do tell me...
Thanks!

Comment: Why not [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)? Since you're using C++/WinRT you are using a C++17 compiler, so everything should be there. C++ exceptions and COM do not mix well. Depending on where your throwing function is being called from, the C++/WinRT library may or may not translate C++ exceptions into `HRESULT` codes. I don't know what exceptions Boost throws, though it may not be one that C++/WinRT knows about.

Comment: I have tried `std::filesystem` earlier, which caused the same problem. It was the reason for me to try and use `boost::filesystem`. Also the exception is not thrown by `boost` (as shown in the edit).

Comment: What is ``basePath`` in this case?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Sorry for late reply I had school. `basePath` = `C:/Users/{Username}/AppData/Roaming/Nanosoft/Expression Simplifier`. In case it is of any use, the above code doesn't cause any issues outside the constructor.

Comment: Also I did some extra debugging and found out that the issue only occurs when `basePath` is a directory in `C:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing UWP applications, be aware that they *by design* run in a 'locked-down' environment. One aspect of this is that they have very limited access to the file system.

A UWP application by default has:

- *read-only* access to its own installed directory (which is typically the 'current working directory' at start-up). This is pointed to by `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation`.
- *read/write* access to its own per user application data directory. The *non-roaming* version is `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`. The *roaming* version is `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder`.
- *read/write* access to a per user application temporary directory that may or may not be there on future invocations of the application. This is `ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder`.

Any attempt to access a file folder other than those above by default will **fail**.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Comment: That would explain why the code is failing. It doesn't, however, explain, why the code allegedly succeeds when put elsewhere. Though I'm having a feeling that it doesn't actually succeed, just that the library (silently) converts C++ exceptions into `HRESULT` codes, that cause the program to respond in a far less spectacular way.

Comment: Hmm makes sense. Thanks! And as said by @IInspectable, I'll look into `HRESULT` too.